# How to create [key:value,key:value] type json in java

Tags: java

I try to  create [key:value,key:value] type json in java but I got only [{key:value},{key:value}] type.

How to create the above type?

Comment: json or properties?

Comment: That isn't valid JSON.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question by adding the code you've written so far and more information on what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

[key:value,key:value] is not a valid json format (http://jsonlint.com/).
You can only have an array of the same elements.
It looks like you are trying to serialize/deserialize a map. In that case, the json would look like:

```
{
  "key1":"value1",
  "key2":"value2"
}
```